# Screenshot capture of google maps which has to be scrolled

Tags: screenshot, google-maps

I have read about this in some questions here , and tried almost all their solutions but none of them have worked for me for one reason or other.
I want to take a snapshot from google maps, directions window which need to be scrolled to see full with given details in the image, i want.

Now I tried many tools like standalone applications : PicPick, DuckCapture, Google map server

Chrome extension - Fireshot, Webpage screen shot

The reasons for not working are like e.g. If I used DuckCapture or PicPick to capture a google map directions page which needed scrolling, this app automatically caused the map to zoom out and loose details(mouse scroll wheel in google maps acts as zoom-in/out, which is same for scrolling down a page!)

Browser extensions just did capture the screen full, nothing outside it.

I am sure there is a simpler way to capture a screen shot of a large google maps window which has to be scrolled, than having to take multiple captures, and then stitch those individual images together in Photoshop!

Has anybody got any good pointers.

Comment: Google Maps’ display is not a scrollable region. So manual stitching is still the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

List all Steps, then Print. Save as PDF if you don't want it on paper.

---

[image: List all Steps]

---

[image: Print]

Comment: Thanks. Stored the pdf using the Pdf955(i.e. Print to PDF955) , still it did only have the "screenful" of the map, not the full one which was scrollable.

Comment: ahh... might be an OS/browser thing. I'm Mac 10.9.5/Safari 7. No issues for me, use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

[ScreenshotCaptor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) will capture scrolling regions.

> Screenshot Captor is a best-in-class tool for grabbing, manipulating,
>   annotating, and sharing screenshots. It's different from other
>   screenshot utilities in several notable ways:
>
> - Optimized for taking lots of screenshots with minimal intervention; stays out of your way until you need it.
> - Super easy to add and edit callout arrows and text boxes.
> - Easy automatic or on-demand uploading of screenshots to image hosting services; easy emailing of screenshots to your friends and
>     colleagues.
> - Take snapshots from webcams; record video with the ESR addon.
> - New optional quick-capture docking bar and post-capture action dialog.
> - Full set of scanner acquisition tools and scanner image correction.
> - Perfect capture of Windows 7 partial transparency effects.
> - **The most powerful scrolling capture tool in the field.**
> - Great special effects, including automatic active window enhancement, ragged edge splicing, pixelation, smart text removal, and
>     many more.
> - Smart autonaming of files, easy renaming and format conversion; automatic image file versioning.
> - Ability to embed textual comments in files or add attractive captions to images and printouts.
> - Unsurpassed multi-monitor support and lots of capture modes: Multimon (multiple monitors), Desktop, Active Window, Region, Windows
>     Object, Scrolling Capture. Each mode has a customizable hotkey for
>     quick access.
> - Unsurpassed support for 3rd party user configurable tools, including file browsers and image editors; extend the program to do
>     whatever you need by interfacing it with other programs.
> - Sidebar thumbnail file browser provides full shell operations, drag and drop support, and right-click actions on screenshots.
> - Deluxe thumbnail maker and watermarker.

[Screenshot Captor 3 - Window Object and Scrolling Capture Screencast Videos](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=29821)

License: Freeware

I have been using it for some years - very useful program, particularly for writing documentation/training material, as you can annotate the screenshots as well.

Note: I haven't tried to capture a scrolling google map with it yet.

Comment: Thanks. Tried Screencaptor. Good one. It almost got my job done, but not exactly. It captures 1 image, then allows me to scroll horizontally on the google maps window where I bring the remaining part of the map/directions into the screen, and capture again, but then it does not just capture the map window , but also the left side pane which has text directions, and that comes in between the two map images which breaks the continutity of two captured images from being one single continuous looking map.

Comment: You can fiddle with the margins and overlap so the two images will stitch together.