# In browser screenshots of large web pages?

Tags: browser, screenshot

I've had this issue coming up now and again.

Sometimes I need to screenshot large pages, however there are situations when the page is too big for any tool to capture.

Right now I'm trying to capture a page 40158px in height, and all screenshot plugins in FF and Chrome just don't do anything (some crash, some just flat out don't do anything).

Today I tried capturing the page with Firefox's command line (Shift+F2) with the command `screenshot --fullpage`, however I get this error:

`[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/gcli/commands/screenshot.js :: exports.items<.grabScreen/< :: line 144" data: no]`

I don't encounter any issues with smaller pages, all tools work fine, however when the height of the page get's huge, no tool I can find can capture the page.

A recommendation was to use a standalone tool, but there are instances where I have to take the screenshot after taking certain actions before I can capture the page (such as infinite scroll pages) and there are times when the page is behind a login screen thus adding more difficulty when using standalone tools or other methods besides in-browser screen capturing.

My guess is that browser settings are limiting memory resources? Is there any way to increase the limitations and allow the browser to capture pages of any size?

Thank you!

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/120266/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-suppor?rq=1

Comment: Relevant: [Screenshot capture of google maps which has to be scrolled](http://superuser.com/a/813956)

Comment: Thank you, however both methods didn't work. Resizing is not an option, as I need the entire page, and the software doesn't handle floating/fixed items resulting in a cascade of duplicates all around