# Is it possible to do scrolling captures of specfic regions?

Tags: windows-10, sharex

Is it possible to do scrolling captures of specfic regions? Currently I do scrolling captures of entire windows and then crop. It's slow and long.Thanks

Windows 10
ShareX

Comment: If you are using Windows then see my answer to [Screenshot capture of google maps which has to be scrolled - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/813912/screenshot-capture-of-google-maps-which-has-to-be-scrolled)

Comment: The question is about ShareX on windows 10. I have made the neccesarry edit. Thanks